# Some Websites/Pings return network unreachable 20.04

Tags: networking, ip, ping, router

I am a fairly new user working through the set-up of a dual boot on my PC.
The Windows OS is able to reach all websites, and I am using the same connection. (Ethernet into a wireless adapter).
The pings tested all reach a Server Not Found page in browser.

Output of reddit ping

```
ping www.reddit.com
ping: connect : Network is unreachable
```

Output of google ping

```
PING google.com(yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=13.6 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=20.0 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=15.0 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=9.66 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=5 ttl=117 time=14.8 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=6 ttl=117 time=9.81 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=7 ttl=117 time=11.7 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=8 ttl=117 time=14.1 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=9 ttl=117 time=10.5 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=10 ttl=117 time=11.7 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=11 ttl=117 time=11.3 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=12 ttl=117 time=71.9 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=13 ttl=117 time=17.9 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=14 ttl=117 time=22.4 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=15 ttl=117 time=15.4 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=16 ttl=117 time=12.8 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=17 ttl=117 time=14.2 ms
64 bytes from yyz12s06-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:400b:802::200e): icmp_seq=18 ttl=117 time=19.1 ms
```

Output of ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:d0:2b:99:89:69 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s25
    inet6 2607:fea8:11df:db00::e2e1/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 161868sec preferred_lft 161868sec
    inet6 2607:fea8:11df:db00:6943:3088:2b87:10f7/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 172790sec preferred_lft 82350sec
    inet6 2607:fea8:11df:db00:b041:a35:2484:6cb6/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 172790sec preferred_lft 172790sec
    inet6 fe80::d07a:4754:42ef:6b40/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:0a:64:b9:3b:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Output of lshw -C network

```
 *-network                
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: 74:d0:2b:99:89:69
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 memory:f7200000-f721ffff memory:f7239000-f7239fff ioport:f040(size=32)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: 24:0a:64:b9:3b:91
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:30 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7103ff
```

This is my first post, please let me know which formatting improvements to make in the future.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Try to not have pictures of text cut and paste and add to the body of the question. Are you sure you do not have a hardware problem?

Comment: @David How would I diagnose the hardware problem? My hardware works while booted on Windows from my 1st drive. Thank you for input on formatting.

Comment: One of the problems with ping is that many servers refuse to respond to requests. None of mine (or my employers’) will answer a ping, and Google does the same with many of their services. It’s not a particularly effective tool at times 

Comment: @matigo The pings presented and tested all correlate to a server not found page in mozilla. They are also servers that do not refuse pings on my other machines.

Comment: I agree with @matigo. I see you are using IPV6. I am using IPV4 and www.reddit.com replies to pings on IPV4.

Comment: @DougSmythies I cannot reach the website through browser initially, the pings are secondary with the same results as browser searches

Comment: Are you sure that you're not on a network that forbids direct access to sites like reddit?  "Network is unreachable" suggests one of two things - either your network connection is misconfigured and there is no route to the Internet, or the network has a firewall or content filter denying access.  Especially with the 'many servers' returning this type of error for you

Comment: Also, on an IPv6-only network you **will not be able to reach websites that have only IPv4 like reddit and others** - if this is your own personal network you configured and built it wrong, if this is someone else's network then you need to talk to them to figure out how to get IPv4 on your internet link

Comment: @ThomasWard This is an out of the box Ubuntu 20.04 installation, no external work has gone into configuring it on my end. The network works as expected on my laptop (ubuntu 20.04) and on my phone + 4-5 other machines.

Comment: @crutio - if the network works as expected on your laptop, compare those network settings. It looks to me as though your routing table is incorrect.

Comment: @Crutio I don't think so, if your network works fine on multiple devices then you need to check their configs and what IPs they have - if they only have IPv6 addresses then something's odd in the network, if they have Ipv4 addresses then something's different about your system.